# Circumnavigate(as connotative)

Tags: expressions

can someone validate this 'circumnavigate' usage for my future expression.

> Life is challenging, but you have to know how to **circumnavigate**
>   yourself towards success.

Can this be possible to use? Thx in advance.

P.s:**circumnavigate**-means you are navigating by means of a boat along any watercourse(river in particular). This is like a rowing/paddling a boat, BUT with a sense of direction to where you wanted to go.

Though you may already know it, I just wanna make it clear to ascertain what we are talking about. Moreover, my goal is to 'step up my game' by saying things that are not commonly expressed yet effective. Please help me IF I am using a very big word in here.

Comment: Have you looked up *circumnavigate* in a dictionary? It does not mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of *circumnavigate* is [here (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumnavigate):

> to go completely around especially by water

And the example phrase is:

> circumnavigate the Earth

In fact, I have never heard *circumnavigate* used in any other context than circling around the globe. I would not use it in this expression, as it does not have any figurative meaning but is generally used to literally mean that someone is navigating around the circumference of the Earth.

*Steer* may be the word you are looking for [(Merriam-Webster definition here)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steer):

> to pursue a course of action

This changes your phrase to

> Life is challenging, but you have to know how to **steer** yourself towards success.

This sounds much more natural.

Comment: As an added bonus, you could also change your phrase to "Life is **treacherous**, but you have to know how to steer yourself towards success" to drive home the maritime metaphor.

Comment: I have also heard **circumnavigate** used to mean making a complete circle around an island: you can book a "Newfoundland Circumnavigation" cruise, for example.  But again, the "circum-" prefix means "make a complete circle around," and this is an essential part of "circumnavigation."

Comment: I've never heard that usage before, but you're exactly right!

Comment: Got it guys. Thx bwahaha! I have just learned a more natural expression, treacherous+steer, excellent! Thx again. Got nothing to say.

Comment: You could make it fit as a *metaphor* but it would take some work.